# Как оптимизировать скрипты?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть много повторяющихся скриптов, например:

```
$('.yo_block').on('mouseenter', function() {
  var offset = $('.yo_block').offset();
  $('#vk_follow_block').hide();
  $('#fb_follow_block').hide();
  $('#google_follow_block').hide();
  $('#youtube_follow_block').show()
    .css({
      'top': offset.top - 120 + 'px',
      'left': offset.left + 0 + 'px'
    })
    .on('mouseleave', function() {
      $(this).hide();
    });
  $(".yo_block").mouseleave(function(e) {
    var $this = $(this);
    var bottom = $this.offset().top + $this.outerHeight();
    if (e.pageY >= bottom) {
      $('#youtube_follow_block').hide();
    }
  });
});
$('.gog_block').on('mouseenter', function() {
  var offset = $('.gog_block').offset();
  $('#vk_follow_block').hide();
  $('#fb_follow_block').hide();
  $('#youtube_follow_block').hide();
  $('#google_follow_block').show()
    .css({
      'top': offset.top - 120 + 'px',
      'left': offset.left + 0 + 'px'
    })
    .on('mouseleave', function() {
      $(this).hide();
    });
  $(".gog_block").mouseleave(function(e) {
    var $this = $(this);
    var bottom = $this.offset().top + $this.outerHeight();
    if (e.pageY >= bottom) {
      $('#google_follow_block').hide();
    }
  });
});
```

Можно ли это сокращать?

Comment: $('#fb_follow_block') и тд определите переменными var blockN....

Comment: Можно! Этот ответ вы хотели увидеть? А по теме, код один  и тот же, выносится в функцию. У вас меняется там только внутренний блок `yo_block` и `gog_block`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно и нужно.

Смотрим внимательно на два куска и понимаем, что они отличаются только именами двух классов. Выносим их в параметры функции и делаем где то так

```
function do($main_block, $social_block) 
{
   $($main_block).on('mouseenter', function(){
            var offset = $($main_block).offset();
            // эти скрытия лучше сделать через цикл
            $('#vk_follow_block').hide();
            $('#fb_follow_block').hide();
            $('#google_follow_block').hide();
            $('#youtube_follow_block').hide();
            $($social_block).show()
                .css({'top': offset.top - 120 +'px', 'left': offset.left + 0 + 'px'})
                .on('mouseleave', function(){
                $(this).hide();
            });
                $($main_block).mouseleave(function(e) {
                 var $this = $(this);
                    var bottom = $this.offset().top + $this.outerHeight();
                 if(e.pageY >= bottom){
                    $($social_block).hide();
                 }
});
                    });
}
```

и вызываем

```
do('.yo_block', '#youtube_follow_block');
do('.gog_block', '#google_follow_block');
```

Comment: Супер! Спасибо!

Comment: А блоки которые hide()? Как быть с ними?

Comment: как видите, я добавил вначале скрытие всех блоков, а потом нужный отображается.

Вы хотите, что бы я написал цикл для скрытия всех блоков?

Comment: Дело в том, что я могу написать сам, но скорее всего получится не акти, хочется сравнивать свой код с кодом специалиста.

Comment: Я не специалист по javascript.
Я настойчиво рекомендую Вам самостоятельно написать.